# Some labels are invisible, when using Dynamics AX 2012 over Citrix

Tags: citrix, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I connect to Dynamics AX 2012 via Citrix. Everything works fine but in some screens the controls have no text. The caption is empty.

I think there are very few users with this problem, but I ask this question to get ideas which could help fix the issue.

Please help, thank you in advance.

UPDATE: The controls are generated by code, they are only visible when we need them.

Comment: This is Citrix related. We are having the problem when connecting via Citrix. But when accessing the environment from Remote Desktop Connection, the problem is gone.

Comment: I'll try to change the screen settings in Citrix, maybe this could fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display issues that occur only in Citrix environments are often caused by one of the various hooks that get used. There are a number of different hooks, but the multi-monitor hook would be the prime culprit to look at.

You can disable hooking for specific processes as follows:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107825

Also check out this article on disabling the multi-monitor hook:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX129712